# Query to return substring from string in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, substring, user-defined-functions

I have a user defined function called `Sync_CheckData` under Scalar-valued functions in Microsoft SQL Server. What it actually does is to check the quantity of issued product and balance quantity are the same. If something is wrong, returns an `ErrorStr nvarchar(255)`.

Output Example:

```
Balance Stock Error for Product ID : 4
```

From the above string, I want to get 4 so that later on I can SELECT the rows which is giving errors by using `WHERE` clause (`WHERE Product_ID = 4`).

Which SQL function can I use to get the `substring`?

Comment: Is it always the last digit before the semi colon?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```
DECLARE @STR AS VARCHAR(1000)
SELECT @STR='Balance Stock Error for Product ID : 4'

SELECT substring(@STR,charINDEX(':',@STR)+1,LEN(@STR)-charINDEX(':',@STR)+1)
```

Comment: +1 -- no need for the added charindex at the end -- it will truncate accordingly.  Here's a Fiddle Demo: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16396

Comment: Thank you so much, tsohtan! I got it.

Answer (score 1):

I'd use `RIGHT` for this:

```
declare @response varchar(100)
set @response = 'Balance Stock Error for Product ID : 4'

select right(@response, len(@response) - charindex(':', @response))
```

Sample fiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/16397 (altered from above)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
DECLARE @String VARCHAR(100)

SET @String = 'Balance Stock Error for Product ID : 4'

SELECT RIGHT(@string, CHARINDEX(':', REVERSE(@string))-2)

OR

SELECT RIGHT(@string,(LEN(@string)+1)-PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @string))
```